# Adding Python to PATH

Tags: python-3.9

I was trying to install XMM-NEWTON SAS to my device. But unfortunately, there is an error.

Checking whether Python is in PATH ... No.

Error: Please add python to your PATH !

I am using a bash shell and have installed python3.9. How can I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The SAS installation script searches for "python" in the PATH, not for "python3" specifically. For a correct installation, you could try to create a soft link for the `python3` binary as `/usr/bin/python`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

This needs to be done with root privileges (thus the 'sudo' in front).

In this way, SAS should find the correct Python version to complete installation.

Comment: Thank you very much. An older version was already been installed in my device. I had removed it and now it works.